# IIS reroute just one site to Apache

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I'm trying to figure out how to reroute just one of our sites from IIS to Apache.  I've followed several online tutorials and posts and nothing is working.  I keep getting:
[image]

I've read that I need to do a reverse proxy using the URL Rewrite feature of IIS.  So I did that and here are my settings:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8088/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Apache is on 8088 and if I hit localhost:8088, it works just fine.  I've also added `IUSR` and `IIS_IUSRS` users to the directory permissions both having read and execute, list contents, and read permissions.  I wouldn't think this would be that terribly hard.

Comment: Mistake 3 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to rewrite IIS to apache, please remember to install ARR.
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing

Then please remember to enable Server node->application request routing cache->Server Proxy setting->Enable proxy.

[image]

Besides, could you access orchestrator.local without URL rewrite rule. Because, if this issue is caused by IIS, you should receive status code more than site can't be reached.

Comment: I have ARR installed and proxy enabled for the server node.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: @dmikester1 The web browser said name_not resolved. Did you register your domain name correctly?

Comment: Maybe not, how do I do that?

Comment: Nevermind, had the IT director add the domain to the DNS server.  Working great!